# How to pass a variable from one method to another in the same activity android

Tags: android

I am new to android and I have tried to pass 2 double variables from one method to another to upload it to the firebase database, but I have not succeeded, the variables come from a location placed on the map. How could I pass the data from searchLocation to SaveDatasMap and upload it to the database?

I tried to put them static in the methods but it does not let me place it. I tried to place the double variables at the beginning but I can not get them to have the value that they are asked to: have the longitude and latitude in their selected variables

```
public  void searchLocation(View view) {


    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Address address = addressList.get(0);
        final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),address.getLatitude()+" "+address.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 double       longitud = address.getLatitude();
   double     latitud = address.getLatitude();










    }


}

public void  SaveDatasMap (View view)
{
    GuardarUbicacion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guardarubicacion);
    final DatabaseReference RootRef;
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Empresa").child(currentUserID).exists()))
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                userdataMap.put("Longitud", longitud);
                userdataMap.put("Longitud", latitud);

                RootRef.child("Empresa").child(currentUserID).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MapTemporalActivity.this, "Se ha guardado la posicion exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new  Intent(MapTemporalActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);


                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    Toast.makeText(MapTemporalActivity.this, "Hubo un  error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

I need to pass the variables longitude and latitude.
I did the data upload to the database but I don't know how to pass the searchLocation's double variables or pass directly address.getLatitude () and address.getLongitude() to the method SavesDataMap

I understand that I would have to do the method in static but it does not allow me android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make these two variable global. instantiate them like this.

`double       longitud;
double     latitud;`

In your searchLocation method do the following:

`longitud = address.getLatitude();
latitud = address.getLatitude();`

Then in the SaveDatasMap method you should be able to get the data.

Comment: When I press the button to save information, nothing happens, did I miss something? I added the setOnClickListener to call that method and removed the identification of the button that was inside the method